# Question about inclined planes and constant velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, gravity

I apologize that this is such a simple question, but I am a beginning physics student trying to learn more in his spare time. I can't find a satisfactory answer anywhere since most inclined plane scenarios involve an object moving down a ramp instead of moving up. If an object moving at constant velocity slides down a ramp, the coefficient of kinetic friction can be found by simply utilizing tan(θ) of the ramp's angle from the horizontal. I know that this is because the kinetic force over normal force simplifies to mgsin(θ)/mgcos(θ) and mass times gravity cancel each other out, leaving sin(θ)/cos(θ). Would the same procedure of using tan(θ) to find the coefficient of friction apply if the object were moving up the slope? If not, why wouldn't it?

Comment: are you saying the the coefficient changes with the inclination of the ramp?

Comment: Yes, as the angle of the ramp increases, the coefficient will increase since tan(theta) grows larger.

Comment: Have you not tried doing the calculation yourself?

Answer (score 1):

So, the coefficient of kinetic friction is the magnitude ratio of the force of (kinetic) friction to the normal force. Your $mg\sin\theta$ theta term is *not the force of friction*, it's the magnitude of the parallel component of the gravitational force.

It's not the case that the coefficient is dependent on the angle - an easy way to see this is to recognize that, although $\tan(0) = 0$, kinetic friction very much exists on horizontal surfaces. The idea behind the determination procedure you're describing is the following: vary the incline until you find *a particular angle* where the block slides down (due to it's own weight) at a constant velocity. If the velocity is constant, the net force on the object is *zero* (there's no acceleration). Since the normal force and the normal component of gravity cancel out, that means that, *at this particular angle*, the friction force cancels out the parallel component. So it has the magnitude of $mg\sin\theta$ only for that value $\theta$; if you change the angle, things get more complicated.

[image]

In other words, it's not a general result, it just describes how to obtain the value using this specific experimental setup.

If you're interested in the scenario where the object moves up the ramp due to some force parallel to the inclined plane, you can apply the same idea - set up the situation so that the velocity is constant. Then the friction and the parallel component of gravity add up to counter the pulling force. Also, if it helps, [here](http://physicstasks.eu/509/a-box-on-an-inclined-plane)'s a worked example that revolves around an object moving both up and down the ramp due to two forces of unspecified magnitude. This time, the ramp is at some arbitrary angle (presumably lower then the threshold value for the object to overcome static friction and start moving on it's own), and the problem involves solving a system of equations.